# Converting strings with exponential number format to double results in NumberFormatException

Tags: java, parsing, double

**Task:**

I am getting technical data from a database and need to process it in order to put it into our database which expects double-values. The entities from the database are elevators, that have technical data like "travel heigth, weigth, ..:".

The source-db gives me `strings` in the exponential number format i.e.: 
`2.8300000000000000E+04`.

I then take this string and convert it into a `Double` like this:

```
public Double getDoubleNumberFromJSONString(String inputValue) {
        return Double.valueOf(inputValue);
}
```

Output: `28.300` (It now is a double)

**Problem:**

Most of the time my approach works, but sometimes the source-db does NOT deliver exponential numbers, but things like this:

`2,200.0 mm` ... so a non-exponential number AND a unit. This results in a `NumberFormatException`.

I dont know how to approach the problem, since the source-input actually can vary greatly:

`1.000 kg` ... `kg 1.000` ... `mm 2,000` ... `350` ... `350.0` ... `350,0` ...

Since our database expects a double-format number, simply forwarding the source-number wont work.

**My solution approach:**

I tried to use `instanceof` to check, if the string actually might be a `Double`:

```
public Object getDoubleNumberFromJSONString(String inputValue) {
    // FIXME Throws an error
    if(Double.valueOf(inputValue) instanceof Double){
        return Double.valueOf(inputValue);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Had to return inputValue in DoubleNumber()! Crash?");
        return inputValue;
    }
}
```

but `Double.valueOf(inputValue)` already throws a `NumberFormatException`, so I dont know how to handle this situation.

**Question:**

How can I parse the input correctly into a `Double`?

Comment: Are you interested in keeping the unit of measurement as well, or just the numeric value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Julien Lopez' proposal in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787050/converting-strings-with-exponential-number-format-to-double-results-in-numberfor?noredirect=1#comment68796829_40787050) I was able to get it to work as expected!

So here is the solution I have constructed:

```
public Double getDoubleNumberFromJSONString(String inputValue) {
    try {
        return Double.valueOf(inputValue);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputValue);
        double value1 = sc.nextDouble();

        sc.close();
        return value1;
    }
}
```

At first the method tries to convert the input string from an exponential number format into a double.

If this fails, a `NumberFormatException` gets thrown.

Then I use a scanner, to scan the string for a double-value and return it.

I have accepted my question as an duplicate of Julien Lopez proposal, since the solution there is very applicable to my question. I answered my own question as an working example.

Answer (score 0):

Could think of string manipulation using ASCII code.
character array -> Filter -> Convert to Double (might be intermediate character sequence)

```
//inside for loop:
if(((int)character[i]>=48 && (int)character[i] <= 57)|| ((int)character[i]==46))
{ //get these elements to new character sequence maintaining the position.
} //when coming out of this block it contains only numerical values.
```

In case if your concerning on instantiating new memory, you may work on deleting the non-numeric values using any of the list ADT's